# Set name for c++ static library in netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, static-libraries

I have a project that was initially named `library-myproject` and is located within the directory `./library-myproject/`. When I compile the project I get an artifact called `liblibrary-myproject` which wasn't a problem while I developed and tested that library, but now when I need to use it as part of another project I can't live with that name.

Going through every single settings in NetBeans 8.02RC I'm still unable to find a way to change the name of the artifact, even if I change the name of the project. Attempting to change the makefile is futile since netbeans recreates it every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit output name from `netbeans` project

> 1. Right click on Library in netbeans
> 2. Open Properties
> 3. Build->Archiver->Output. At the end you will see name of lib (SomeName.a)
> 4. Change it to suiltable name you need.
> 5. Rebuild Project. You are good to go...